# SELECT then filter based on previous SELECT

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible, *without inserting the first result set into a temporary table or repeating the select statement*, to do something like the following?:

```
SELECT    ID, ForeignKeyID, SomeValue
FROM      MyTable
WHERE     (SomeValue > @SomeValueFilter)

SELECT    ID, IntegerValue
FROM      MyOtherTable
WHERE     {ID is in the ForeignKeyID set from the previous SELECT}

SELECT    ID, SomeDateTime
FROM      MyYetAnotherTable
WHERE     {ID is in the IntegerValue set from the previous SELECT}
```

Expected output:

```
Table 1: ID, ForeignKeyID, SomeValue
Table 2: ID, IntegerValue
Table 3: ID, SomeDateTime
```

EDIT: Added a third select which means I can't use a CTE.
EDIT2: Different data type and expected output.

Comment: I think you mean `CTE`

Comment: either a CTE or subselect using exits or IN clause

Comment: So, do you want 3 result sets as your output then?

Comment: Yes, that would be the ideal scenario.

Comment: Ok, see my edit

Comment: I would think a simple `JOIN` of the tables would give you better result.  Why 3 result sets?

Comment: I don't want to duplicate rows in the output and the result sets are used to build 3 collections containing objects of each type in the consuming code. The third table's rows are nested children of the second, second the first. Could probably do something with XML or JSON but that seems nasty...

Comment: What is your 'consuming code' ?  It sounds like you are trying to implement some sort of eager fetching for an ORM of some sort.  If that is the case, they typically are prefetched with either a `LEFT JOIN` (with smart parsing of the result set to eliminate the duplicate values) or else a subsequent select using an `IN` clause.  (Where the list of `ID`s are populated from the first query results, but executed in a separate statement.

Comment: You're right, but transferring data across the wire is more expensive than filtering it at source and the typical ways go for the easier, more expensive option. It might be a pre-mature optimisation, but I would prefer the data to come out of the database in the 'right' format so I don't have to repeat code if I need to implement a different ORM layer. I could even lazy-load rather than fetch eagerly, but trying to find the most optimal way that SQL will let me do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CTE?  But maybe this doesn't satisfy the "without repeating the select"?  Not quite sure what that means...

```
;WITH t1 as (
  SELECT    ID, ForeignKeyID, SomeValue
  FROM      MyTable
  WHERE     (SomeValue > @SomeValueFilter)
)
SELECT   ID, Value
FROM     MyOtherTable
WHERE    ID IN (SELECT ForeignKeyID FROM t1)
UNION
SELECT   ID, Value
FROM     MyYetAnotherTable
WHERE    ID IN (SELECT ForeignKeyID FROM t1)
```

**EDIT:**
If you don't need to maintain the datatypes you can use CAST or CONVERT along with UNION, but that obviously will only give you a single resultset.

If you need to maintain the datatypes then I don't see a way around repeating the first query if you can't use a temp table.

If you need three separate result sets then I think you are definitely going to be repeating the query.

Comment: Sorry, I knew in my head I can't use a CTE for what I want but failed to illustrate why in my question.

Comment: Can't you just add a UNION?

Comment: That only works if the Value columns are the same data type. I'm trying to achieve the creation of a DataSet where each part depends on the previous select which having to save each result in a temp table.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you can add your schemas and expected output to the question then.  Given your question as it stands this is perfectly viable.

Comment: Added my expected output and improved column names.

Comment: Thanks, I was assuming the answer would be a "no, unless you comprimise here...". Will wait to see if anyone has any epiphanies and, if not, mark this as the answer.